# Not adding data to SQL database through Entity Framework model C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This question might be asked but I could not find the answer for now so please help me with this. I'm trying to add a new row into my SQL database through EF model. Is there anything wrong because it looks okay but actually does not insert anything to the table.

```
private void Bsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using(var db = new Models.CompanyDBEntities())
        {
            db.Clients.Add(new Client
            {
                name = nameTB.Text,
                age = Convert.ToInt32(ageTB.Text)
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

EDIT** So now I'm adding a Change Tracker to see what's going on:

```
        if (db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()){
            db.SaveChanges();
            var clients = (from c in db.Clients select c).ToList();
            string updated = "";
            foreach (var c in clients)
            {
                updated += c.Name;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(updated);
        }
```

The message box does show up the name of current clients in the data together with the name I just added. I think the problem here is .SaveChanges() it's not working. I did not find the solution yet.

Comment: Are you using EF6 or EF5?

Comment: you should have left "Attach" in your question, so that other people see the problem... now it's confusing. @ThanhTDao

Comment: I'm using EF6. The problem comes from the .savechanges() as I tested but i just cant find a solution for this.

Comment: I record a complete simple test here, maybe you can find some clue https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2uwmsr93yqn51w/EF6_Client_Test.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try add Parameterless Constructor to your class and try again, just guess:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {

    }

    public string name ...
    public int age ...
    ...
}
```

and use parentheses when new: 'new Client **()** {'

```
        db.Clients.Add(new Client()
        {
            name = nameTB.Text,
            age = Convert.ToInt32(ageTB.Text)
        });
```

Comment: I've tried and they actually do the same thing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **Sql Server Profiler**, and inspect the Query executed against your statement, most probably you will find your answer.